# modify all files in directory. While keeping file structure the same

Tags: file

I do not know what it is called but this is what I am wanting to do. Imagine that you have a directory named (program) then you have three other directories beneath that named 1,2,3. Each of these have 10 files in them either in python or php or what ever.

What I am wanting to do is change a little bity bit of code in each one using a find and replace in notepage ++. Is there a way to basically have every file combined for this one find and replace then when you are done just save it and have them go back into the individual files and directories like before. Is this even possible, has anyone even wanted to do this?

Comment: You could do that with a bash script. (But instead of combining the files you'd just open each file individually)

Comment: Please tag your question better, so that you could get better answers.